# Everytime no changes with method haschanges()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm using a TableAdapter for a simple software in visual basic.
I entered a query -Search by name- but i want check for changes before start the search (because i'll lost the changes with the search).
My idea is this:

```
If TimeBankDataSet.HasChanges() Then
        Try
        Select Case MsgBox("Save the canges before searching?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel)
            Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                Me.Validate()
                Me.PeopleBindingSource.EndEdit()
                Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TimeBankDataSet)
                MsgBox("Saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
                Exit Sub
            Case MsgBoxResult.Cancel
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    End If
```

But there are never changes..

Solved adding: `Me.PeopleBindingSource.EndEdit()`

Comment: Not enough of an example to help you at this point. `HasChanges` are only needed with datasets with related datatables where you have to update the rows accoording to the rowstate table by table. If you make changes to the underlying table as such, then you have to do an `AcceptChanges` which would then commit the changes to the underlying table... Could you provide more information as we may then be able to help?

Comment: I can't post images.
I'm using a TableAdapter with details and a BindingNavigator.
I don't know what information you need ...

Comment: oh, I solved adding this: Me.PeopleBindingSource.EndEdit()